# New activity in another package kill my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-package-managers

**I am starting a new intent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.xxxxxx.xxxx", "xx.xxxxxx.xxxx.Activity"));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But sometimes new application have some error and I must kill them, and I must turn it again.

**I tried to add:**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but it's not working.

[SOLUTION]:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.xxxxxx.xxxx", "xx.xxxxxx.xxxx.Activity"));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

SecondActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.xxxxxx.xxxx", "xx.xxxxxx.xxxx.Activity"));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // saveInSharedPreferences...
            finish();
    }

MainActivity
    onResume() {
        getWithSharedPreferences...
    }
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat Error

Comment: I do not have any log...

Comment: Application is not responding (Force close, wait), when i click close, my app will be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. If you want to start another `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()` you cannot use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. When starting an `Activity` that will return a result, the target `Activity` must run in the same task.

There isn't much you can do about this.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe can I create a new activity in the new task? And there I will add the above code? When I get an answer I finish new activity and send answer to MainActivity

Comment: Sure, you could do that. It might confuse your users though. And you can't use `startActivityForResult()` to send the result back to your `MainActivity`. You'll need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` or `SharedPreferences` or something like that to communicate between the 2 tasks.